# Custom Tab in My account Page goes to 404 in Magneto 2

Tags: magento2, module, tabs, myaccount

It added the Buttton but when i click on it it goes to 404 error.

My Folder Structure be Like

[image]

And my code is :
index.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Mod\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
        $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
        /*echo 'Hello World 11111  ajjjjjjjjjjjjj';
        exit;*/
    }


}
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
       <route id="routename" frontName="routename">
            <module name="Demo_Mod" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_Mod" setup_version="2.1.1" active="true"/>
</config>
```

customer_account.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer- 
   account-navigation-custom">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">routename/customer/index</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Setup</argument>
            </arguments>
         </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

routename_customer_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/e 
    tc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<update handle="customer_account"/> 
<body> 
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title"> 
            <action method="setPageTitle"> 
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My 
Setup</argument> 
            </action> 
 </referenceBlock> 
 <referenceContainer name="content"> 
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_tab" template="Demo_Mod::mytab.phtml"> 
    </block> 
</referenceContainer> 
</body> 
</page>
```

mytab.phtml

```
<?php 
 // Add Some Code Here for design
?>
<span> My Setup Custom Tab.. </span>
```

and last file registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_Mod',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: follow this link --- https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/add-custom-tab-on-customer-account-section-in-magento-2-317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename this file name **routename_customer_index.xml** with **routename_index_index.xml**.

And in **customer_account.xml** this file update below content

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer- 
   account-navigation-custom">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">routename</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Setup</argument>
            </arguments>
         </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

There you added wrong URL **routename/customer/index**, just use **routename** there and then clean and flush Magento cache and check.

Or Follow [this article](https://www.kishansavaliya.com/magento2/how-to-add-custom-tab-in-customer-account-magento-2.html)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I have renamed the file it still goes to 404

Comment: @Prits, updated my answer, please check and let me know if it helps, Thanks :-)

Comment: Yupp it works Thanks for that :)

Comment: will you please tell me what's the issue as it is not working with my code.

Comment: @Prits, Because you create controller directory name "Index" and you're using "customer" there, If you want to use customer in url then you have to use Customer as Controller directory name and also in Action file you need to change path then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out if i want to add two tabs then i want to create a new module or i want to add same code in that ?

Comment: You need to create new controller action, and layout file and you have to define new tab in customer_account.xml file that's it.

Comment: thanks for that info.

Comment: i have faced another problem on that phtml file i want email id of logged in user .How will i get that ?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/ Try to follow this

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kishan I have tried ( Object Manager ) this method and it works but if i want to ( Block class ) method then i want to create full block for that and connect that block with my phtml file am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, Exactly, You need to create one block file and you can use that class name in your XML file and you can use that in your template file.

Comment: I faced a weird problem in my custom tab if the user is logged out and the tab is open and i refresh it it doesn't redirect me to signup page ?

Comment: It shows me this error when i change my controller file erroe : ' Type Error occurred when creating object '

Comment: I have asked another question please have a look https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316827/getting-error-type-error-occurred-when-creating-object