# Getting error " Type Error occurred when creating object "

Tags: magento2, login, redirect

When i edit in constructor file of my custom module it give me this error " Type Error occurred when creating object " i don't know what i am doing wrong i use same code for creating a Block and its working.

My Controller code is :

```
<?php
namespace Dealers\Validation\Controller\Valuation;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_customerSession;
     
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    array $userdata = []
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();   
    parent::__construct($context, $userdata);
}

public function execute()
{
    /*if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
    }*/
    $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
    $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
}
}
```

I want to redirect it to login page if user is not logged in.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my working code, you can follow this

```
protected $customerSession;
protected $urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession; 
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    //Redirect to login page if customer is not logged in
    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("You must be logged in to add/update product");
        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        return;
    }
    $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
    $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
}
```

This will check if customer is logged in, it will redirect to login otherwise. It also sets return URL so that after login customer will redirect back to current URL

**Edit:** Context error fixed

Comment: Thanks for the help but still i have found the same error " Type Error occurred when creating object "

Comment: If you have used `parent::__construct($context, $userdata);` then just remove `$userdata` from your constructor and just use `parent::__construct($context);`

Comment: Will you  share your full controler file @Shoaib

Comment: It give me this error " Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory::isLoggedIn() "

Comment: It worked Thanks @Shoaib Will you please tell what's the issue in previous code.

Comment: will you please look into this how to solve this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316851/magento-2-how-can-i-update-product-price-from-frontend

Comment: There is no issue in my code, it is working code.

Comment: Sure I will look into your issue

Comment: Done already @Shoaib 
I have another issue will you help me with this
I want all product so i used $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create(); $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); return $collection; But it doesn't return disabled product i also want that .

Comment: Done Accepted your answer 
I have asked seprate question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810173/show-all-product-in-magneto-2
Please look into it @Shoaib

Comment: Sure, checking.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update below content in your file

```
<?php
namespace Dealers\Validation\Controller\Valuation;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_customerSession;
        
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();   
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('customer/account/login', ['_current' => true]);
        }
        $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
        $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
    }
}
```

You missed `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context` this in your construct.

After changing above content try to run below commands once.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

We don't need to pass `userData` array to parent construct, because if you'll open below file.

> vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php

There you can see we need to pass only single arg to our parent construct and it's context. So just remove second arg and try to compile again.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: @Thanks for the help Kishan added screenshot after di:compile command gave me that error

Comment: Answer updated. Please check @Prits

Comment: Thanks it worked @Kishan
If i want to redirect it to login page if not logged in then it would done before execute right!

Comment: It give me this error " Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory::isLoggedIn() "

Comment: @Prits, I have updated my answer, please update code and let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Done Thanks 
will you please look into this how to do that any idea will help
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316851/magento-2-how-can-i-update-product-price-from-frontend

Comment: Approve answer if it helps, Thanks :-)

Comment: Approved it already @Kishan
Please look new question which asked in previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110389/discussion-between-prits-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: will you please help me with this question @Kishan it would be really helpful.