# Magento 2 - How Can I Send Success and Error in JSON and from Frontend update product price and enable/'disable?

Tags: magento2, php, price, frontend, programmatically

**Ajax runs on page load i want to run it on button click.**

I create one Module and make a custom tab which is display some product with name and price and if the product is enable/disable.
I want that user update that price from front-end and enable and disable that product from front-end.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my Controller File

```
<?php
namespace Deal\Val\Controller\Valuation;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $customerSession;
protected $urlInterface;
protected $customer;
private $productAction;

public function __construct(
    Action $productAction,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Dealers\Validation\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("You must be logged in to view product");
        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        return;
    }
    /*$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $this->customer->saveproduct($data);*/
    $productIds = [47];

    $storeId = 0;

    $attributes = [
        //'status' => Status::STATUS_ENABLED,
        'price' => 70
    ];

    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
    $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
    $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
}
}
```

This is my Model File

```
<?php
namespace Deal\Val\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;

 class Customer
{
/**
 * @var Action
 */
private $productAction;

public function __construct(
    Action $productAction
) {
    $this->productAction = $productAction;
}

public function execute()
{
    /** Array of product ids */
    $productIds = [47];

    /** Contains the id of the store in which you would like to enable/disable the product */
    $storeId = 0;

    /**
     * You can put any number of product attributes here. However, in the scope of this code we are going to
     * only enable/disable the product.
     */
    $attributes = [
        'status' => Status::STATUS_ENABLED
    ];

    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
}
}
```

This is my JS file

```
require(["jquery"],function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#price" ).click(function() {
        let customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'customer/valuation/index'?>";
        let dataid = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                dataid: dataid
            },
            complete: function(response) {             
                console.log(response); 
            },
        });
    });

});
console.log('aa');
});
```

**How can i send response success or error in JSON format.**

Comment: You want to disable from the frontend right ?

Comment: Yes and update price too, thanks for the reply @Tanmay

Answer (score 1):

In your model file, you first need to load the product, then update it's price and save it.

I am updating your model code:

```
<?php
namespace Deal\Val\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;

 class Customer
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** Array of product ids */
        $productIds = [47];
        foreach($productIds as $id){
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
            $product->setPrice(100); //Update anything here
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: It gives me this error
" type Error occurred when creating object: " @Shoaib

Comment: Can you show full error message?

Comment: Updated the screenshot of error @Shoaib

Comment: instead of calling model file, you can move update product code in your controller. I have also created this type of module where user can update their products, I did the same, updated product in controller file

Comment: On moving that in Controller file still got the same error " Type Error occurred when creating object " @Shoaib

Comment: Can you share your updated controller code?

Comment: Updated my Controller FIle @Shoaib

Comment: Please remove this modeling calling from constructor as well `\Dealers\Validation\Model\Customer $customer,`

Comment: Still give the same error @Shoaib

Comment: Please add updated controller code in question

Comment: It works Thanks will you tell me how to send JSON data in response success and failure.@Shoaib
Please look into this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317177/how-to-get-base-url-in-theme-custom-js-file-and-how-to-return-response-in-json-f @Shoaib

Comment: That's great. Sure I will look into this link

Comment: Actually i have done with another way so doesn't know about it that's why didn't mark it yet.@Shoaib
see that question i have updated my controller file https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317177/how-to-get-base-url-in-theme-custom-js-file-and-how-to-return-response-in-json-f

Comment: Sure, no problem