# How to Get Base Url in Theme Custom JS file and how to return response in JSON format?

Tags: magento2, javascript, json, base-url

I have created a module in which all the things is done just 2 things are remaining .

How to add Dynamic base url in Magento 2 theme JS file. ex : http://127.0.0.1/projectname how to get that dynamically.

How to pass success or error in JSON format using Module -> Model

it would be really helpful.

```
<?php
namespace Namespcae\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_configReader;
protected $_pageFactory;
protected $customer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader,
    \Namespcae\Modulename\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_configReader = $configReader;
    $this->customer = $customer;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{   
   $productIds = [5];

    /** Contains the id of the store in which you would like to enable/disable the product */
    $storeId = 0;

    /**
     * You can put any number of product attributes here. However, in the scope of this code we are going to
     * only enable/disable the product.
     */
    $attributes = [
        'status' => Status::STATUS_ENABLED
    ];

    $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
}
}
```

**How can i send response success or error in JSON format.**

Comment: Check this similar question [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/get-base-url-or-dynamic-url-in-view-js-or-html-files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/get-base-url-or-dynamic-url-in-view-js-or-html-files)

Comment: @RahulBarot is right, this question is similar, you can find your answer there, but I didn't get JSON part of your question, why do you want json response from model, we always want response from controller, but I don't understand why from Model?

Comment: Actually i have executed my data from model if i move that t controller that would be good i will do that and from that point how to return JSON response from that controller part on success or failure.@shoaib

Comment: how to get base url in Theme js file not in any module js file @RahulBarot

Comment: Updated my controller file please check @ShoaibMunir

Comment: + for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For json response from your controller just use array and user echo or return in json format. Example code:

```
public function execute()
{   
    $response = ["success"=>"", "error"=>""];
    $config = $this->_configReader->load();
    $response["base_url"] = $this->getBaseUrl();
    $response["custom_data_1"] = "My data";
    $response["custom_array_1"] = [123,456,789];
    //Condition to check if error
    $response["error"] = "Error occured";
    //Success check
    $response["success"] = "Successfully done";
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

if `return json_encode($response);` not work for you then you can try `echo json_encode($response);`

In your controller you can also use `$this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage("Success message here")` or `$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Error message here")`

For base url part, you can use this code in any of the js

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
], function($,url){
    url.setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
    varBaseUrl = url.build('');
    //Your other code here
});
```

Comment: Give me error " Type Error occurred when creating object " @Shoaib

Comment: For URL part " Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined "

Comment: Did you use `'mage/url'` in require and used `url` in function brackets `()`? this is very important, otherwise you can't use `url`

Comment: Yes used exactly same @Shoaib

Comment: can you share screenshot of your js code?

Comment: Updated in my question!

Comment: I have updated my answer, actually string is needed to be passed in this function. The string would be the request URI after base url. Now you need base URL and not the URI, you can pass empty string here

Comment: The BaseUrl perimeter is empty i want is http://127.0.0.1/projectname that part.
and in url perimeter it has object.
@Shoaib

Comment: I have updated my answer, this is tested code, it should work now

Comment: Works like a charm Thanks for that @Shoaib

Comment: Updated my controller file with updated method will you tell me how to send SUCCESS or ERROR in JSON Format. @Shoaib

Comment: Answer updated, please check

Comment: Your static code works but how would i know the success of " $this->productAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId); " that part @Shoaib

Comment: Use try catch, if it works it wont go to catch, add success code in try

Comment: Yes correct i have just used that. How to get that value in js response.@Shoaib

Comment: parse ajax response using `var result = jQuery.parseJSON(res);`, then you will get `result.success`

Comment: Now i get the ID of product so should i make the HTML for that in js or use any other way to create that template.@Shoaib

Comment: It is better that you create html first, make it display none, and after your ajax assign values to the html and make it display block

Comment: I have created a template how would i pass id from js to that template @Shoaib

Comment: You don't have to pass id, you need to assign html in div with class, something like this `jQuery(".mainProduct .name").html(result.product.name)` for this you need to set data of product in your controller response

Comment: I have a custom attribute in my product backend in which i have entered some text.
How to get products based on that attribute if some has same value using Controller or Block. @Shoaib

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110596/discussion-on-answer-by-shoaib-munir-how-to-get-base-url-in-theme-custom-js-file).